# Not able to access web server on Raspberry pi on local network

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi, webserver, hotspot

I am running a flask web server on raspberry pi 3 B+. I am able to access the page `192.168.4.1:5000` on the berry(chromium).

The same raspberry pi is also acting as a wireless LAN router. I am able to connect my other devices like ipad and phone to this wifi network. So there is no additional router in this network where I might need to do port forwarding.

Issue is, I am not able to access `192.168.4.1:5000` from any other device on this local network.

Please note that I am not using the ethernet port on the raspberry pi.

Please help!

Comment: are you able to ping the rpi ip from other devices?

Answer (score 1):

Okay so the solution was to add a route.
I did
sudo ip route add 192.168.4.0/24 via 192.168.4.1 dev wlan0

Now I am trying to figure out how to make this route persistent.

Answer (score 0):

Use a port scanner to find the ip such as: [Port Droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stealthcopter.portdroid)

You can also use NMAP for Windows or MacOS

You can also try this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

It will make the server externally visible.

Comment: I know the IP.. Issue is non-connectivity

Comment: I have done this already. In fact, the same python app is visible and accessible over the local network when hosted on a windows PC

Comment: Sometimes the ip changes. So you can try running a network scan.

Comment: So I ran it and got the same IP. Do note that its a static IP.

Comment: In that case... Can you ping the PI?

Comment: How to ping from iPad?

Comment: I downloaded an app and tried to ping but it times out

Comment: Try rebooting the PI

Comment: Done. Still not pinging.

Comment: Check your Firewall

Comment: The rpi has no firewall installed

Comment: Also i am not able to ping the ipad or my phone from rpi

Comment: Can you use Internet using the PI's network? By firewall I have also meant Windows or PC's firewall.

Comment: Yes I am able to use the internet if ethernet cable is pligged in OR if I connect to the home WIFI

Comment: I am using only my ipad and phone to connect to the Pi network so no firewalls involved